# Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $x=2\theta+sin2\theta$ and $y=1-cos2\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, parametric

> The parametric equations of a curve are
>   $$x=2\theta+\sin2\theta,\:y=1-\cos2\theta.$$
>   Show that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan\theta$.

I can use the chain rule to get
$$\frac{dx}{d\theta}=2+2\cos2\theta$$
$$\frac{dy}{d\theta}=2\sin2\theta$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{d\theta}\div\frac{dx}{d\theta}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin2\theta}{2+2\cos2\theta},$$

but I'm not sure how to get to a final proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{2 sin 2\theta }{2+2 cos 2\theta }=\\\frac{2 *2sin \theta cos \theta   }{2+2 (2 cos ^2\theta -1)}=\\=\frac{4 sin \theta cos \theta  }{2+4 cos^2 \theta -2}=\\\frac{4 sin \theta cos \theta  }{4 cos^2 \theta }=\frac{sin \theta }{cos \theta }=tan \theta   $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $1+\cos2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta$, and $\sin 2\theta = 2\sin\theta \cos\theta$

Answer (score 1):

use the double angle formulas

$$
\sin(2 \theta) = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta \\
\cos(2 \theta) = 2 \cos^2 \theta - 1
$$
When you simplify, you'll get a $\cos \theta$ in numerator and denominator that'll cancel and you'll be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that $$\frac{2\sin 2 \theta}{2+2 \cos 2 \theta} = \frac{\sin 2 \theta}{1+ \cos 2 \theta} \\ = \frac{2 \cos \theta \sin \theta}{2 \cos^2 \theta} = \tan \theta$$
I used the identities $\cos 2\theta = 2 \cos^2 \theta - 1$ and $\sin 2\theta = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$